# Life length of an animal given a density function and current age

Tags: statistics

The question I'm struggling with while studying for my statistics final exam is as follows:

"The life length of a specific animal (in years) is random and has density
$f(x) = (10-x)/50$ for $0 \le x \le 10$, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Suppose one animal of this kind has already lived for 5 years. Let $Z$ be the life length of this animal. Find $E(Z)$ and $V(Z)$."

I think it might have to do with the conditional probability of finding $E[Z|T=5]$, but I'm not sure how to incorporate this to find the life length of the animal. What would be a good way to start approaching this problem?

Comment: I think you are looking for $E[Z \mid Z>5]$ and $\textrm{Var}(Z \mid Z>5)$.  It could help if you had the conditional density for $Z$ given that $Z>5$, which amounts to a truncated  version of the original distribution.  What have you tried?